# Using sed to remove a block of text bash script

Tags: bash

I have a file with the above content

```
# secureboot
service setlockstate /sbin/setlockstate
    class core
    oneshot
    seclabel u:r:vold:s0

#mdbd
service mdbd /sbin/mdbd
    class core
    socket mdbd stream 660 system system
    disabled
    seclabel u:r:mdbd:s0

service shelld /system/xbin/shelld
    user system
    group system
    class main
```

How can I delete a block in the file with the above content?

```
# secureboot
service setlockstate /sbin/setlockstate
    class core
    oneshot
    seclabel u:r:vold:s0
```

Comment: What did you try and what was wrong with it?

Comment: So which pattern you want to delete? `service setlockstate /sbin/setlockstate` this one?